Spamed by Google Assistant and Gemini messages: I can't stop hundred notifications per hour. My Google Assistant and Google notifications are disabled
This morning my smartphone (an A55, Android 14 (6.1.43-Android14-1)) is spamming notifications inviting me to try the Gemini AI and/or to use Google Assistant.

My Google Assistant is disabled in my account
Google and Google Play aren't allowed to send normal notifications
Google isn't allowed to send notification when its screen is locked

I've rebooted my phone.
But I'm receiving more than one hundred notifications per hour interrupting my work as a popup, or doing a bip, while appearing on my locked screen. Like:

"Google Assistant is ready to help you, Activate",
"Try: Say 'what the weather?' to Gemini"
"Say: 'How to set an alarm to 7am?' to Gemini"

Endlessly, on the locked screen.
How to stop these notifications coming?

Google and Play Store app are just the "frontend apps". Notifications are handles by Google Play Services. I would try to clear app cache on Google Play Services.

Shouldn't this be an answer? If I do this, Andrew grizzles at me!

Possible dupe? How to stop ads for turning on Google Assistant?

I didn't had any success. Eventually, I've turned off my phone during an hour, and during that hour I believed that I was hearing same notifications, elsewhere far, in my building.
I turned my phone on again, and notifications restarted quickly. And after a while, they went off. I guess it was a Google service network problem: something that gone havoc for few hours.
Maybe one tech website will explain what event happened today, later.
